# Error When Trying to Restore Image Using Clonezilla

Tags: windows, partitioning, clonezilla, imaging

I have two Dell Dimension 4700 computers.

One has a 83GB IDE drive, the other an 80GB SATA drive.

I created a 20GB partition on the IDE computer and installed Windows XP on it.

I used Clonezilla to save the partition to an external drive. This worked fine.

Now when trying to restore the image to the SATA computer it proceeds to go to the part lone screen and says "This is not a parclone image."

Then it says to check the log.
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Something went wrong!!

Then it says that the image may be correct (but it passed the check image test) or there is no /home/pathtoimage/sda1*! Yet again it appears to be there when looking at it.

All the parclone.log says is that: This is not a parclone image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah going into expert options and selecting ntfsclone did the job